# 31 101 трасс или трасса?

Tags: орфография

В ходе задания проверено 31 101 кабельных трасс (или кабельная трасса?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

31 101 (... сто одна) **кабельная трасса**.

Смотрите всегда по последнему компоненту числительного: одна - трасса; две, три четыре - трассы; пять,..., десять и т.д. - трасс.

Comment: **проверена** ... трасса

Comment: не очевидно...
Согласование требуется, при другом порядке: 101 трасса проверена.
В нашем случае используемый вариант едва ли не предпочтительна.